# Remove spaces in Hololens

Tags: c#, hololens

I am creating an app for the hololens and I have some troubles when I run my app more than once. The first time that you run the app, the space is created well. However, if you run it in other room, the space, which was stored before, interferes with the actual mapping.

I would to like to know if someone knows how to remove spaces from the code, since you can do it going to Settings -> Systems -> Spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to manage spaces from apps, but generally you should try to make your app location agnostic. This thread might offer a bit more insight: https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/2103/currently-active-space-and-worldanchor-store

Comment: That thread does not help me. It does not contain the solution that I want.